# Changing the tile when notification comes in windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-8

Can i Change the Tile When any Notification comes in Windows Phone. I want to change the Count on the Tile When Notification Comes In Windows Phone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First select the tile

```
var primaryTile = ShellTile.ActiveTiles.First();
```

Then update it, where `count` is the count you want it to show.

```
primaryTile.Update(new FlipTileData { Count = count });
```

Comment: yes you are right,But where can i write this Code. As i know there is no method called when it received Tile Notification

Comment: What do you mean? How are you getting the notifications? The code above is good for example if you're setting it from the app or using a background agent.